# Selecting from a database from Today onwards

Tags: php, mysql, database, date

Im trying to select a bunch of stuff from a database. Each have a date and i'd like to only display the ones whose date is equal to today onwards.

`$sql="SELECT * FROM bs_events WHERE NOW() ORDER BY eventDate ";`

I have tried looking everywhere and cannot find anything.

Thanks for any help guys

Comment: How are the dates stored (datetime, date, timestamp, int - what field type) and do you know that you are not comparing anything in your query? It doesn't seem you looked hard enough, and it's not that complicated to compare a few dates by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

where EventDate >= now()

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE eventDate >= CURDATE()";
```

should fix you up

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM bs_events WHERE NOW() <=  eventDate   ORDER BY eventDate ";
```

Comment: Now, it will return empty result set or today's  records only

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bs_events WHERE eventDate >= CURDATE() ORDER BY eventDate";
```

Answer (score 0):

Important: Using NOW() and CURDATE() does make your query invalid for the query cache. On many request - f.e. the homepage - this could cause performance loss.

I prefer the following snippet:

```
$oDate = new DateTime();
$sQuery = "
    SELECT field1, field2 
    FROM bs_events 
    WHERE eventDate >= '".$oDate->format("Y-m-d H:i")."'
    ORDER BY eventDate
";
```

This will achieve your goal, but will cause the query cache to be used for a full minute. Ofcourse you can tweak this to a larger or smaller amount of time.